# Disallow overriding of access lists in .htaccess (Blacklist based AllowOverride)

Tags: apache-2.2, access-control-list

We have some web software with its own `.htaccess`. No on our internal test servers we want to configure some access permissions (htaccess passwords)

We want to avoid modifications specific to the test-server in the `.htaccess`.

We do this in the vhost configuration of Apache 2.

`.htaccess` contains:

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

How can we block those settings? Is there a blacklist-based way to the `AllowOverride` directive? Something like `DontAllowOverride Order Allow` ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is an [excellent documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride) available for everyone.

```
AllowOverride Limit
```

would **allow** `Order`/`Deny`/`Allow` instructions.

```
AllowOverride AuthConfig, FileInfo, Indexes
```

Will allow anything except `Order`/`Deny`/`Allow` instructions' and also any `Options` as they need to be listed.

But as stated by @jeffatrackaid it would certainmly be better to `AllowOverride Nonoe`.

You would get more speed from Apache and put all needed configurations in Virtualhosts/Directory/Locations sections. `.htaccess` files have nothing to do with `.htpassword` security.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that vhost directory configurations are processed after htaccess files.  So in this case, you cannot restrict users since the htaccess file would allow them all.

You may want to look into either:

1. blocking htaccess on a per-directory basis.
2. Checking into the Require
   and Satisfy arguments.  If you add password protection in your vhost
   configuration, you can use the Satisfy argument to require the user
   both match the htaccess criteria and the password.

Of course test.

In general, I recommend disabling htaccess on the directory your are trying to secure if are not sure that the users will not overwrite the file.  If there are directives you require in the htaccess file, you can always make it owned by a user that does not have write access so it cannot be changed.

For some clients, when we cannot remove htaccess entirely, we often set the htaccess file to be owned by an admin level user and chmod 644. This prevents the everyday webmaster from changing the file.